# Scala worksheet evaluation results not showing up in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying out scala for the first time and am following this page to set upmy first scala project : 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started-intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html

However despite this on creating a simple worksheet with println("hello") upon evaluation no results come up.
What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Most likely, automatic evaluation is not enabled in worksheet options. To open worksheet settings, click on the "wrench" icon (rightmost icon in the worksheet menu bar), then it has quite obvious name (but I don't recall exactly, and don't have IntelliJ handy to look it up).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple configuration issue in the IDE

Comment: What is stackoverflow even for, if not for these kind of questions? By the way even upon running the worksheet it did not print anything.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but in my subjective opinion this question is unlikely to be helpful for future readers - the problem you're facing is likely either a configuration issue, a bug in this particular version of the IDE, or a mix of the two. If that's the case, it won't be relevant to everyone else, and might actually be misleading if similar problem arises in the future. Hence, I'm expressing my _subjective_ opinion that it should be closed/put on hold.

Comment: And to answer your other question :) Again, in my opinion stakoverflow is for questions that are relevant for the software developer community in general. "Please debug my code/configuration for me" are rarely useful to more than one person and actually are [specifically discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I dont think this is that. I would be quite conscious about doing something like that. This is a general query that could indeed have been faced by many people. So in my subjective opinion I think you are being unreasonable.

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? I have been running into this. It seems scala 2.13 does not work with IntelliJ. I ran into this after following the tutorial on the scala website, using 2.13 as suggested. Using 2.12 seems fine. (Although scala in IntelliJ seems quite glitchy in general.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue that is only happens on Scala 2.13. (I have not exhaustively tested it though.)

I have used 2.12.9 successfully.

I opened an issue on the Scala docs project too.

https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/issues/1486